# Zend Propel no data commitmend

Tags: php, mysql, database, extjs, zend-framework

The program uses the Zend-framework and Propel.
My '_form_genehmigt.phtml' refers me to my index-page and executes the updateAction in Antragpeer.php when I press the save button, but the data is not committed. There is no new entry in my MySql-database. But there isn't a error message in firebug either.

//UrlaubController.php

```
public function updateAction() {
        $antrag = AntragPeer::update($_POST);   
        if (!count($antrag->getValidationFailures())) {
            //$antrag->save();  //nötig??
            $this->view->success = true;
            $this->view->Urlaubsantrag = $antrag->getId();
        } else {
            $this->view->success = false;
            $this->view->errors = $antrag->getValidationFailures();
        }
    }
```

//Antragpeer.php

```
public static function update($post) {

        $con = Propel::getConnection();
        $con->beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (!empty($post['id'])) {
                $antrag = self::getById($post['id']);
            } else {
                $antrag = null;
            }
            if (is_null($antrag)) {
                $antrag = new Antrag();
            }
            $antrag->fromArray($post, BasePeer::TYPE_FIELDNAME);
            if ($antrag->validate()) {
                $antrag->save($con);

                // Speichere Id wenn neuer Eintrag
                if (empty($post['id'])) {
                    $id = date('y').date('m').date('d').'-A'.$antrag->getId();
                    $antrag->setId($id);
                    $antrag->save();
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $con->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $con->rollBack();
            if ($e->getMessage() != "") Zend_Registry::get('log')->log($e->getMessage(), Zend_Log::ERR);
        }

        return $antrag;
    }
```

//_form_genehmigt.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php
    echo $this->extArrayStore('benutzer', array('id'=>'integer', 'label'=>'string'), AclBenutzerPeer::getBenutzerIdformBenutzerStore());
    ?>

    Ext.onReady(function() {

        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init(true, {showDelay: 0, dismissDelay: 0});

        Ext.define('Gesamt', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
                {name: 'bezeichnung', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Resturlaub_vorjahr', type: 'string'}
            ],
            idProperty: 'id'
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Gesamt',
            storeId: 'gesamtstore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/Verwaltung/getprogrammbereicheforprojekt?format=json',
                extraParams: {
                    Resturlaub_vorjahr: <?php echo ((($this->data instanceof Gesamt) && $this->data->getResturlaubVorjahr() != "")
                    ? $this->data->getResturlaubVorjahr()
                    : (($this->mode == "new" && !empty($this->data['Resturlaub_vorjahr']))
                        ? $this->data['Resturlaub_vorjahr']
                        : "''")); ?>,
                    Anspruch: <?php echo ((($this->data instanceof Gesamt) && $this->data->getAnspruch() != "")
                    ? $this->data->getAnspruch()
                    : (($this->mode == "new" && !empty($this->data['Anspruch']))
                        ? $this->data['Anspruch']
                        : "''")); ?>,
                    Gesamt: <?php echo ((($this->data instanceof Gesamt) && $this->data->getGesamt() != "")
                    ? $this->data->getGesamt()
                    : (($this->mode == "new" && !empty($this->data['Gesamt']))
                        ? $this->data['Gesamt']
                        : "''")); ?>,
                    csrf_token: '<?php echo HelperFunctions::getCSRFToken(); ?>'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'Gesamt',
                    totalProperty: 'totalcountgesamt'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: {
                    fn:function(records, operation, success) {
                        var modelDest = Ext.getCmp('Resturlaub_vorjahr');
                        if (this.getById(modelDest.getValue()) === null) {
                            modelDest.setValue('');
                        }
                        if (modelDest.store.data.length > 0) {
                            modelDest.setDisabled(false);
                        } else {
                            modelDest.setDisabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.define('Urlaubsantrag', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
                {name: 'typ', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'typ_icon', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'datum', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'datum_grid', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'mitarbeiter_name', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'kommentar_grid', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'mitarbeiter_id', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Von_Datum', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Bis_Datum', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Anzahl_Tage', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Antrags_Datum', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Resturlaub_Tage', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Gesamt_Anzahl_Tage', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Kommentar', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Genehmigt_Von', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Jahr', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Genehmigt', type: 'boolean'},
                {name: 'mitarbeiter_gesamt', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Resturlaub_vorjahr', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Anspruch', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Sonderurlaub', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Gesamt', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Jahr', type: 'string'}
            ],
            idProperty: 'id'
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Urlaubsantrag',
            storeId: 'Urlaubsantragstore',
            sorters: {
                property: 'created_at_grid',
                direction: 'DESC'
            },
            sortOnLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                //url?
                url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/urlaub/update?format=json',
                extraParams: {
                    antragId: <?php echo (($this->data instanceOf Antrag)
                    ? $this->data->getId()
                    : "''"); ?>
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'array',
                    totalProperty: 'totalcount'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                'load': function (records, options, success)  {
                    if (Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Urlaubsantragstore').getTotalCount() > 0) {
                        Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Urlaubsantragstore').each(function (record) {
                            if (record.get('Genehmigt') === false) {
                                Ext.getCmp('formularmeldungen_erledigt').show();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Ext.getCmp('formularmeldungen_erledigt').hide();
                    }
                }
            },
            autoLoad: <?php echo (($this->data instanceOf Antrag) ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>,
            remoteFilter: true
        });

        var formPanelAntrag = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: 'form-ctantrag',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            id: 'formPanelAntrag',
            trackResetOnLoad: true,
            width: <?php echo Constants::EXT4_PANEL_WIDTH ?>,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    border: false,
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Urlaubsantrag',
                            defaults: {
                                labelWidth: 200,
                                anchor: '100%'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                                    title: 'Allgemeine Angaben',
                                    defaults: {
                                        labelWidth: 200,
                                        anchor: '100%'
                                    },
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                                            name: 'id'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'datefield',
                                            id: 'Antrags_Datum',
                                            name: 'Antrags_Datum',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Antrags Datum',
                                            format: 'd.m.Y',
                                            value: '<?php echo date("d.m.Y") ?>',
                                            tabIndex: 1
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'timefield',
                                            id: 'datum_zeit',
                                            name: 'datum_zeit',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Zeit',
                                            format: 'H:i',
                                            value: '<?php echo date("H:i"); ?>',
                                            tabIndex: 2
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'combo',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Mitarbeiter',
                                            name: 'mitarbeiter_id',
                                            id: 'mitarbeiter_id',
                                            store: 'benutzer_store',
                                            queryMode: 'local',
                                            displayField: 'label',
                                            valueField: 'id',
                                            value: <?php echo (($this->mode == "new") ? Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId() : "''"); ?>,
                                            forceSelection: true,
                                            tabIndex: 3
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Resturlaub Vorjahr',
                                            name: 'Resturlaub_vorjahr',
                                            id: 'Resturlaub_vorjahr',
                                            store: 'gesamtstore',
                                            queryMode: 'local',
                                            displayField: 'label',
                                            valueField: 'Resturlaub_vorjahr', //value + 'Tage'
                                            value: <?php echo (($this->mode == "new") ? json_encode($this->data['Resturlaub_vorjahr']) : "''"); ?>,
                                            disabled: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                                            name: 'Anspruch Aktuell',
                                            id: 'Anspruch',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Anspruch dieses Jahr',
                                            disabled: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                                            name: 'Gesamt',
                                            id: 'Gesamt',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Gesamt',
                                            disabled: true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                                            name: 'Vorhanden aktuell',
                                            id: 'Vorhanden_dieses_jahr',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Vorhanden dieses Jahr',
                                            disabled: true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },{
                                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                                    title: 'Urlaubs Angaben',
                                    defaults: {
                                        labelWidth: 200,
                                        anchor: '100%'
                                    },
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'datefield',
                                            name: 'Von Datum',
                                            id: 'VonDatum',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Von',
                                            tabIndex: 4
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'datefield',
                                            name: 'Bis Datum',
                                            id: 'BisDatum',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Bis',
                                            tabIndex: 5
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                                            name: 'Anzahl Tage',
                                            id: 'AnzahlTage',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Anzahl Tage (Abzgl. Wochenenden)',
                                            tabIndex: 6
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                                            name: 'Sonderurlaub',
                                            inputValue: '1',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Sonderurlaub',
                                            anchor: '100%',
                                            tabIndex: 7
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'displayfield',
                                            name: 'Resturlaub tage',
                                            id: 'Resturlaub',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Resturlaub',
                                            disabled: true
                                        }

                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                                    title: 'Kommentar',
                                    cls: 'fieldset_innerdiv',
                                    defaults: {
                                        labelWidth: 200,
                                        anchor: '100%'
                                    },
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'textarea',
                                            name: 'Kommentar',
                                            id: 'Kommentar',
                                            tabIndex: 8
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                                    title: 'Genehmigt',
                                    cls: 'fieldset_innerdiv',
                                    defaults: {
                                        labelWidth: 200,
                                        anchor: '100%'
                                    },
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                                            name: 'Genehmigt Ja',
                                            id: 'Genehmigt_ja',
                                            inputValue: '1',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Ja',
                                            anchor: '100%',
                                            tabIndex: 9
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'checkbox',
                                            name: 'Genehmigt Nein',
                                            id: 'Genehmigt_nein',
                                            inputValue: '2',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Nein',
                                            anchor: '100%',
                                            tabIndex: 10
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'combo',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Genehmigt Von',
                                            name: 'mitarbeiter_id',
                                            id: 'genehmigt_von',
                                            store: 'benutzer_store',
                                            queryMode: 'local',
                                            displayField: 'label',
                                            valueField: 'id',
                                            value: <?php echo (($this->mode == "new") ? Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId() : "''"); ?>,
                                            forceSelection: true,
                                            tabIndex: 11
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: '{LB_CANCEL_AND_BACK}',
                    icon: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/images/<?php echo Constants::ICON_LOESCHEN; ?>',
                    handler: function () {
                        window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/urlaub/index?csrf_token=<?php echo HelperFunctions::getCSRFToken() ?>";
                    },
                    tabIndex: 26
                },
                {
                    text: '{LB_SAVE_NEW}',
                    id: 'btn_save',
                    icon: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/images/<?php echo Constants::ICON_SPEICHERN; ?>',
                    formBind: true,
                    handler: function(){
                        if (formPanelAntrag.isDisabled() == false) {
                            this.up('form').getForm().submit({
                                url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/urlaub/update?format=json',
                                submitEmptyText: false,

                                success: function (form, action) {
                                    window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/urlaub/index?csrf_token=<?php echo HelperFunctions::getCSRFToken(); ?>';
                                },
                                failure: function (form, action) {
                                    goToTop();
                                    flash('error', {
                                        title: '<?php echo Text::LB_FORMPANEL_FLASH_ERROR_TITLE ?>',
                                        msg: '<?php echo Text::LB_FORMPANEL_FLASH_ERROR_MSG ?>',
                                        fadeOut: 1,
                                        delay: 7000
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    tabIndex: 27
                }]
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="form-ctantrag"></div>
```